# awk commands within python script

Tags: python, awk

I need to write a python script where I need to call a few awk commands inside of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
input_dir = '/home/abc/data'

os.chdir(input_dir)
#wd=os.getcwd()
#print wd
os.system ("tail -n+2 ./*/*.tsv|cat|awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"};{split($10,arr,"-")}{print arr[1]}'|sort|uniq -c")
```

It gives an error in line 8: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Is there a way I can get the awk command get to work within the python script?
Thanks

Comment: escape the quotes around \t?

Comment: Why? there is nothing sed/awk/sort/uniq can do that you cannot do directly from within python and as a bonus you get a solution that runs on all platform python is ported to!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have both types of quotes in that string, so use triple quotes around the whole thing

```
>>> x = '''tail -n+2 ./*/*.tsv|cat|awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"};{split($10,arr,"-")}{print arr[1]}'|sort|uniq -c'''
>>> x
'tail -n+2 ./*/*.tsv|cat|awk \'BEGIN{FS="\t"};{split($10,arr,"-")}{print arr[1]}\'|sort|uniq -c'
```

Comment: stack overflow doesn't format it correctly in the `code` blocks, but if you copy paste the line into the interpreter you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`:

```
import subprocess
COMMAND = "tail -n+2 ./*/*.tsv|cat|awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\t\"};{split($10,arr,\"-\")}{print arr[1]}'|sort|uniq -c"  

subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell=True)
```

As TehTris has pointed out, the arrangement of quotes in the question breaks the command string into multiple strings. Pre-formatting the command and escaping the double-quotes fixes this.

Comment: Adding even more `|cat`s to the pipeline would make it even better, no?

Comment: Why should he use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`? Thanks.