# How to execute awk command inside python

Tags: python, awk

I am trying to run the following `awk` command inside python but I get a syntax error related to the quotes:

```
import subprocess
COMMAND = "df /dev/sda1 | awk /'NR==2 {sub("%","",$5); if ($5 >= 80) {printf "Warning! Space usage is %d%%", $5}}"

subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell=True)
```

I tried to escape the quotes but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python subprocess: pipe an image blob to imagemagick shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105904/python-subprocess-pipe-an-image-blob-to-imagemagick-shell-command)

Comment: Proper escaping would be like this: `COMMAND = "df /dev/sda1 | awk 'NR==2 {sub(\"%\",\"\",$5); if ($5 >= 80) {printf \"Warning!  Space usage is %d%%\", $5}}'"`

Comment: You have a unclosed quote. I suggest you running it in your terminal before you actually do it in python.

Comment: Use triple quotes on the `COMMAND` string. But why are you doing it like this? Just use awk, or just use Python. What's the point of using both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
COMMAND="df /dev/sda1 | awk 'NR==2 {sub(\"%\",\"\",$5); if ($5 >= 80) {printf \"Warning! Space usage is %d%%\", $5}}'"

subprocess.Popen(COMMAND,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

Comment: `shell=True` is not recommended

Answer (score 4):

You may want to put `'''` or `"""` around the string since you have both `'` and `"`.

```
import subprocess
COMMAND = '''"df /dev/sda1 | awk /'NR==2 {sub("%","",$5); if ($5 >= 80) {printf "Warning! Space usage is %d%%", $5}}"'''

subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell=True)
```

There also seems to be a relevant answer already for this as well: [awk commands within python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675211/awk-commands-within-python-script)

Comment: In that case I get a: No such file or directory

Comment: That could be the output for the `df` command. `df` should be used on filesystems and not on disks.

Answer (score 2):

I was writing a python script for my deployment purpose and one part of the script was to explicitely kill the process if its not stopped successfully.

Below is the python code which actually performs
Find the processId of the process named myApplication
`ps -ef | grep myApplication | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}`
and then perform
`kill -9 PID` //where PID is output of earlier command

```
  import subprocess
  import signal

  def killApplicationProcessIfStillRunning(app_name):
      p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-ef'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', app_name],stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      p3 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-v' , 'grep'],stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      p4 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{print $2}'],stdin=p3.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      out, err = p4.communicate()
      if out:
          print 'Attempting to kill '+app_name +' process with PID ' +out.splitlines()[0]
          os.kill(int(out.splitlines()[0]),signal.SIGKILL)
```

Now invoke the above method as

`killApplicationProcessIfStillRunning(myApplication)`

Hope it helps someone.